# How to do SFTP in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have checked the SimpleFTPSample from apple. It works fine. My question is how to do secured FTP in iPhone? Is the any samples available?

Answer (score 0):

Start with GCDAsyncSocket to give yourself a sockets layer; grab the Putty source code and get porting.

Putty is very well written but you are going to need to be able to read ANSI C and to be able to convert to objects if you are going to use it.

Comment: You can compile C on the iPhone. Pardon my stupidity, but why would you convert to objects?

Comment: Yes you can compile C on the iPhone of course! But at some point you need to interface the C to your views, and you have to start thinking in objects. You might want to keep a C model or you might want to adapt it all as a learning exercise. On the app store button - I am lazy. I really, really mean to blog and fix up the public face of me one day.